# Typescript enum stored in json

Tags: json, angular, typescript, enums

I'm working with Typescript and Angular 2 and
I want to create enum dynamically from some json data. 
For instance I want to set enum for a dropdown menu and want to get the options from a json. How to do this?

Comment: sounds like all you need is to display a list of items, why bother with the enums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Typescript, `enums` are transpiled as JS arrays (see [Enums in TypeScript: what is the JavaScript code doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278095/enums-in-typescript-what-is-the-javascript-code-doing)).

So, if you want to dynamically load an enum, you just have to load an array.

But if your goal is to create a select out of this enum, you should definetly deserialize your json and pass it to a component with an embedded `select`, creating `option`s from your object using an `*ngFor`.

The easiest way would be to format your JSON this way:

```
{
   "selectData":[
                     { 
                      "key":"foo", 
                      "value":"bar"
                     }
                ]
}
```

This way you can load your json and iterate on `selectData` array, using `key` and `value` values to create your select.

Comment: Well, this is quite the format I am searching for.
But how to parse it to enum. I get the data through http.get and subscribe it when my page loads.

Comment: @DilyanGeorgiev why do you need the enum though? That's not even something meaningfull at runtime. Enums are only available at build and compile time.

Comment: Enum is not something you can create on runtime, since the runtime part is Javascript. So the enum is just an `array` as I said. You just need to `JSON.parse` your json result in your `subscriber` and pass `yourJsonObj.selectData` to your select component using data binding.

Comment: Ok, I understand! Thank you!