# Can I set a common function to enum in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have defined an enum like this:

```
enum VideoCategoryEnum {
  knowledge = 0,
  condition = 1,
  interview = 2,
  speech = 3,
  entertainment = 4,
  news = 5,
  advertisement = 6,
  others = 7,
}
```

I want to set a common function to all the enum so that I can do:

```
VideoCategoryEnum.tostring() // 'VideoCategoryEnum'
```

Is it possible to do this? thanks.

Comment: You want to stringify the name of the enum with a custom `.tostring()` method? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191451/get-name-of-variable-in-typescript...but this appears to be an X/Y problem. *Why* do you want to do this?

Comment: @AbanaClara or maybe provide some functions like "getName" and "setName".

Comment: @AirNoir why would you want to modify the name of the enum programmatically?

Comment: @AbanaClara  No, I don't want to modify name. I am just wondering if I could give a name to enum.

Comment: @FrankerZ  it's useful to me.  I am trying to write a common function to loop the enum props with i18n translated.  I don't want to pass a second parameter like getEnumList(enumObject, 'enumeName').

Comment: @FrankerZ I just tried the method provided by the link. It could only get the variable name, but not the enum's name. for ex.   getEnumList(enumObject) ,  the method will return 'enumObject' instead of 'VideoCategoryEnum' .

Answer (score 2):

Typescript is basically just a compile time type checking built on top of Javascript. Typescript enum types are just map (object) under the hood, you can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278095/enums-in-typescript-what-is-the-javascript-code-doing)

Therefore, implement a `toString` function to an enum type is quite straight forward. You can do it after defining the enum type. Just make sure that you don't put your implementation on `.d.ts` files because these won't be compile into javascript code.

According the the answer link above, your enum type would be compiled into:

```
var VideoCategoryEnum;
(function (VideoCategoryEnum) {
   VideoCategoryEnum[VideoCategoryEnum["knowledge"] = 0] = "knowledge";
   VideoCategoryEnum[VideoCategoryEnum["condition"] = 1] = "condition";
   // ...
})(VideoCategoryEnum || (VideoCategoryEnum = {}));
;

/* would equivalent to the following:
   VideoCategoryEnum = {
      "knowledge": 0,
      "condition": 1,
      ...
      "0": "knowledge",
      "1": "condition",
   }
*/
// since it's just basically an object, you can do whatever you want with it like below
// your implementation of toString
VideoCategoryEnum.toString = function() { return 'VideoCategoryEnum'; };
```

Comment: It resolves the problem, but makes the declaration of enum more complicated also. Anyway, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

[ts-nameof](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-nameof) should do what you are looking for.

There's a couple of options if you're using babel, and one for tsc.

In your above example, it is simply used as such:

```
enum VideoCategoryEnum {
  knowledge = 0,
  condition = 1,
  interview = 2,
  speech = 3,
  entertainment = 4,
  news = 5,
  advertisement = 6,
  others = 7,
}

nameof(VideoCategoryEnum); // VideoCategoryEnum
```